# Mark positions of spawnpoint in editor

Tags: unity

I am creating a digital boardgame, which consits of muliple boards, between which the gamepieces are moved by the players.

The script of the game board needs a 2D array of positions to know where to move a gamepiece when it recives one.
Currently to mark the positions on the game boards, I added placeholder gameobjects to the prefab and named them "spawnpoint\d".In the `Awake()` method I use `Transform.Find()` to search for those gameobjects. Then, after I save their positions I call `Destroy()` on them, so they do not show up in the game.

I see two problems:

1. This is done for all Instantiated game board, altough the positions are the same on all of them.
2. I read that using `Transform.Find()` is heavily discourged by the experts in the community.

I wish to store the spawnpoint positions in a static array, so all instances refer to the same data. Furthermore I wish to easily modify these positions in the editor with visual help.

I tried serializing static members, but those do not show up in the editor to be able to modify.

```
    [SerializeField]
    public static int TestNumber;
```

TLDR:
**How to make static members visually changeable from the Unity editor?**

Comment: Transform.Find() is fine to use as long as your core game logic does not need to use to call it in update. Doing so for a couple of positions once at the start of the game is ok. You could add as well a script on the spawn point that is adding itself to the list before deleting, so you do not need to search for the spawn point, the point can be given the reference of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLDR: How to make static members visually changeable from the Unity editor?

First of all, there is **no way** to expose static variable to inspector. Although there is similar way [to achieve this result via ScriptableObject](https://danielilett.com/2019-10-07-unity-tips-4-scriptableobjects/). (Centralize data to one ScriptableObject) But it is not quite the same and do have some restriction to reference scene stuffs.

If I understand correctly, you want to share "2D array of positions" (List of Vector2?) for all boards. So that all boards does not have to repeat the same process of finding placeholder/record position/then destroy them.

#### To visualize your place holder while able to adjust them

- I don't know how you visualize your place holder nodes initially, but you could use icon styling. (drop down menu near game object name) This enable you to see them and select them easily in Scene window. There are 2 styles to choose from, with and w/o name. The node content will be empty; not contain any rendering element that will appear in the game. [image]
- You may use your same method of hardcoding the spawnpoint by name and `Transform.Find()` to reach them. But you should contain them to some root node, instead of scene-wide. This is not too bad since `Transform.Find()` find only 1 level of child node not entire scene.
- Instead of getting their Vector3 position then destroy them. You keep them around (since they have no render part to interfere with game view), save their 'Transform' reference to  use as a mean to get position.
- Since you said you want to share them to future board object, you could pass them via static again, as you suggested.
- There is no more need to display them in inspector, since they are already visualized in scene view. And also editable/movable. (also remember that you lose changes while editing in play mode, find some way/plugin to save your work)

sample script for this idea could be like:

```
class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Specify a scene object that contain all placeholders")]
    [SerializeField] Transform m_Root;

    static Transform[] s_AllPositions; // Shared between all Board instances. Could change to 2D array of your choice of implementation
    
    void Awake( )
    {    
        // first board component that started will initialize this array,
        // second board onward will not repeat this work
        if( s_AllPositions == null )
        {
            s_AllPositions = new Transform[10];
            for( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ )
                s_AllPositions[i] = m_Root.Find( $"spawnpoint{i}" );
        }
    }
    void Update( )
    {
        s_AllPositions[i].position // Could use them like this
    }
```

#### Post script

> Transform.Find() is heavily discourged by the experts in the community.

**IMO>** It is very fine to use in one setup frame. Not called repeatedly in Update-manner since it can struggle the FPS.